# mysql_query not inserting anything into my database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this bit of code here:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'DB.php';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)
    or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$timPaid = $_POST['timPaid'];
$rennyPaid = $_POST['rennyPaid'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName (`name`, `date`, `amount`, `timpaid`, `rennypaid`)
        VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$amount', '$timPaid', '$rennyPaid')";

$result = mysql_query($con, $sql)
    or die("Error: ".mysql_error());

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

DB.php is my database settings. I call a query to it on page load and it connects and pulls data fine, so I know it's not an issue there. I also don't get any errors. I get a status code 200 OK on the post.

Here's the ajax post:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var amount = $('#amount').val();
var timPaid = $('#timPaid').val();
var rennyPaid = $('#rennyPaid').val();
var data = $('#newSubmissionForm').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    data: data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function()
    {
        window.location.href = '';
    }
 });
```

Does it have something to do with me serializing it?

I hope this is enough info. Thanks!

Comment: What is $tableName?? You are Not specifying it..

Comment: You're closing your connection using `mysqli` while you using `mysql_query`. Seems there must be typo there.

Comment: The server will return a status 200 even if there is an error in your code. If you're using Google Chrome, you can easily see the full response from your ajax request in the developer tools. One thing I think might be happening is that you have some apostrophes that get sent to the server and you are not escaping your data before inserting it into your database. Try using `mysql_real_escape_string()` (ie. $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])) and you should be fine

Comment: @Rikesh I changed them all to mysql instead of mysqli

Comment: @JonathanPellerin I wasn't using any apostrophes but thanks for the advice. The initial problem was that the query and connection were reversed in the mysql_query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) requires first parameter as query and second parameter as connection object (optional)

change this

```
$result = mysql_query($con, $sql);
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

Also you used `mysql` for connection and query but you used `mysqli` to close the connection.

Comment: Well it worked once.. Can't insert anything else. No errors. Probably has to do with my table.

Comment: Data was inserted once. Won't do any more.

Comment: @TimothyOwen May be your ajax call is not calling.

Comment: Well I mean it did it once.

Answer (score 1):

You have likely just switched the $sql and $con statement. in mysql_query $sql should be the first parameter. It's easy to forget, since mysqli_query should have $con as the first. :/

php die() statement is the same as exit, and will end the script with status 200. Likely you DO get an error in the output. Try viewing it in e.g developer console (Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

1. check in internet explorer which code is generated
   (inspect element)
2. add to the beginning of your session php file

> ```
> <?php
> echo '<pre>';
> var_dump($_POST);
> die();
> ?>
> ```

This will show the values that are sent to the database.